# Are the VB.NET code snippets available for C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

#### Question

I was wondering if anyone knows where I might find C# versions of the VB.NET code snippets built in to Visual Studio (2008)?

#### What are Code Snippets?

VB.NET has a wide-ranging collection of snippets that cover most of the basic tasks one might want to accomplish, i.e. File I/O, LINQ, DB connectivity, and so on. C# has a much smaller and narrower library, mainly stuff for NetFX 3.0, Refactoring, and something called "other", among one or two other items.

Comment: Which snippets in particular are causing you problems.  VB has a collection of code snippets as well and most of the same that C# has

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two resources that I've used before to get C# code snippets are

[Got Code Snippets](http://gotcodesnippets.com/) and [Visual Studio 2005 Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718338.aspx) which will give you a collection of over 400 different types of C# code snippets.

If there is a particular VB code snippet that you like you can alway use a tool to translate the code in C# and then [create your own code snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k(VS.80).aspx).

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually considering quickly throwing together a tool that would hook up to one of those online services and translate them in a single batch

Answer (score 3):

The code snippets should still work. Tools => Code Snippets Manager..., or the chord:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

For example, `prop` <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> gives:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

with ability to step through the pieces to change. The full list is in the manager.

Comment: Actually more snippets for Visual Basic are provided out of the box than are for C#.

Answer (score 1):

Doh! Further searching revealed the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/aa718338.aspx

> Visual C#
>
> Task-Based Code Snippets This is a set
>   of task-based code snippets in C# that
>   can help you with programming tasks
>   ranging from working with databases
>   and windows applications to writing
>   mobile device applications and
>   networking programs. Note: Visual
>   Basic versions of these snippets are
>   included in the box.

Looks like this is exactly what I was looking for.